# javascript window.open not opening in the same window internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

I've currently have an issue with internet explorer 10 when calling window.open with same window name.

When calling window.open multiple times with the same name then multiple windows are opening instead of the page loading in the same window.

```
window.open("http://www.example.com","windowname","location=0,menubar=0,height=596,width=792,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0,resizable=1,left=0,screenX=0,top=0,screenY=0");
```

After some investigation of the user setting (which is a default setup for the company) there is list of sites in the trusted sites, when the domain www.example.com is added to the list of trusted websites then the page loads in the same window.

I've tried assigning the result of window.open to a variable and then calling window.close() before opening a new popup window but this causes a cross domain error.

```
var variable1 = window.open("http://www.example.com","windowname","location=0,menubar=0,height=596,width=792,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0,resizable=1,left=0,screenX=0,top=0,screenY=0");

variable1.close();
```

Can anyone offer an insight into which user setting causes this to happen? and how I always open the popup page in the same window?

Comment: you'll need `document.location.href = 'http://www.example.com'`

Comment: I think the case is about other things @Joeytje50

Comment: I don't think this will work because this is a popup window not the main window. I don't have control of the popup window to change the document.location.href.

Comment: @user3262939 how about `variable1.document.location.href` instead? Will that work? Or does that give your another X-domain error?

Comment: @Joeytje50 cross domain issue.